# KeyError for 2D dictionary when called in a loop but very same code works outside the loop

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I'm populating a 2D dictionary by looping over its elements. This is the initialization of the dictionary:

```
    My2Ddict = defaultdict(dict)
    row_index = 0
    with open('/Path/To/CSVFile.csv', 'rb') as f:
        next(f) # skip header line
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
        row_index += 1
        My2Ddict[row_index]['title'] = row[2]
```

Then I try to add a new key-values to each item in ''My2Ddict'':

```
    for story in My2Ddict:
        My2Ddict[story]['title_length'] = len(My2Ddict[story]['title'])
```

Here I get the error:

```
    KeyError: 'title'
```

But if I run the following command outside the loop, it works fine and returns a numeric value:

```
    print "len(My2Ddict[1]['title']): %n" %len(My2Ddict[1]['title'])
```

I have checked and this does not seem to be an indexing issue. Have got no clue how to proceed...

Comment: `story` is not equal to 1 when you get the error

Comment: try this: `for story in My2Ddict: print 'title' in My2Ddict[story]`. If one of them is False, you'll get this error.

Comment: Thanks @Julien Spronck! This helped troubleshooting the error. It was in fact an indexing issue since My2Ddict is indexed from 1 by row_index but later, story starts from 0.